# How to take a window from its process and set it as a child of another process?

Tags: autohotkey

I remember coming across some code that consisted of a simple AutoHotkey command, that would let you take a window and set it as a child of another process. From my tests at the time, this did not seem to be a visual thing either, the window for all intents was "seen" as a child of the process it was assigned to.

Well I cant seem to find it that command now, I scoured the docs and even searched around, I just keep coming across "move window" or "move to x" search results.

I remember some time ago, when I asked Hellbent to explain the inner workings of one of his scripts, [Dock-It](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=103165&start=20), him mentioning that it works by taking the source window and setting it as a child to another window.

I looked at his source code, and it looks very complicated but it looks like it is down to line [180](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=458443#p458443):

```
DllCall("SetParent", "uint", This.Child.Hwnd , "uint", This.InnerPanel.Hwnd )
```

So I tried passing the window ID of a test child window in place of `This.Child.Hwnd` and the window ID whose parent process I wan the child window to be parented to in place of `This.InnerPanel.Hwnd`:

```
DllCall("SetParent", "uint", 0xdc07cc, "uint", 0x70bf8)
```

But all that happens is that the child window disappears, I am not sure if it gets closed or something.

DLL calls are way beyond me, So I don't even know where to begin. Can someone tell if this feature ever existed as a AutoHotkey Command? what about in V2?

If not I would really appreciate a DLL example on how to do this.

Thank you.